# behavior mask angular8 in ngx-mask

Tags: angular, typescript, mask

I have a component where I need a mask to be according to the parameters entered by the user and that if it passes the 11 digits of cpf the field will have the mask of cnpj. Below is the code snippet:
I am using ngx-mask;

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" formControlName="cpf_cnpj" [mask]="mask" (keyup)="cpfcnpjmask($event)">
```

```js
 cpfcnpjmask() {
    const value = this.dadosBancariosForm.get('cpf_cnpj').value;
    console.log(value, value.length,this.dadosBancariosForm)
    if(value.length <= 14) {
      this.mask = '00.000.000/0000-00'
    }
    else {
      this.mask = '00.000.0000-00'
    }
  }
```

In this code it takes only the first chew and never falls in the second. Someone would have the solution to this impasse or some mask that accomplishes this purpose.
Thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is inverse, change if block by else and try to use 9s...

`static MASCARA_CPF = "999.999.999-99";`

`static MASCARA_CNPJ = "99.999.999/9999-99";`

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you want I think this is the way I could think of
Please try changing the condition like this i think it will work.

```
if(value.length > 11){
  console.log('here');
  this.mask = '00.000.000/0000-00';
}
else if(value.length == 11){
  this.mask= '00.000.000/0000-00';
}
else if (value.length < 11){
   this.mask= '00.000.0000-00';
}
```